# ngRoute error with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I get this error, described on this [url](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myProject&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.7%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngCookies%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.7%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngCookies%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A24%253A186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A23%253A252)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A23%253A495%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A37%253A427%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520h%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A37%253A275)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A37%253A444%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A35689%252FScripts%252FExternal%252FAngular%252Fangular.1.4.7.min.js%253A7%253A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:38:184%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20h%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:37:444%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20h%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:41:35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:35689%2FScripts%2FExternal%2FAngular%2Fangular.1.4.7.min.js:19:463):

> Description This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some
>   exception. The error message above should provide additional context.
>
> Using ngRoute In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to
>   its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x
>   or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

But I don't see why it's going wrong, I've added `ngRoute` like so:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myProject", ["ngRoute"]);
```

*(and a whole bunch more, but I don't think that matters)*

And the ngRoute JS file is added in the `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/External/Angular/angular-route.js"></script>
```

What else should I look at?

Comment: Is the `angular-route.js` file accessible? Can you navigate to `~/Scripts/External/Angular/angular-route.js` in the browser?

Comment: `http://localhost:00000/Scripts/External/Angular/angular-route.js` works.

Comment: `~/Scripts/External/Angular/angular-route.js` should be added after `angular.js`

Comment: It is:
`<script src="~/Scripts/External/Angular/angular.1.4.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/External/Angular/angular-route.js"></script>`

Comment: add  angular-ui-router.js

Comment: Isn't that a different way of doing routing?

Comment: Possibly it is completely unrelated to `ngRoute` and you are missing some other dependency. Please double-check if all your module dependencies can be matched.

Maybe it also helps if you use the non minified version of angularjs to get a more elaborate error message.

Comment: Could you post what other angular dependencies you're using, and the order you're loading them? It might be one of them that's interfering.

Answer (score 1):

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
```

Add external file for angular-route.js after angular script in **index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

working code at W3school:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing